# How to fix WordPress WooCommerce Uncaught Error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, uncaught-exception

I get this error when I activate my WooCommerce Plugin:

Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property “translations” on null

> An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 81 of the file /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/helper/class-wc-helper-updater.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "translations" on null in /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/helper/class-wc-helper-updater.php:81 Stack trace: #0 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WC_Helper_Updater::transient_update_plugins() #1 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #2 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-includes/option.php(2053): apply_filters() #3 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-includes/update.php(393): set_site_transient() #4 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-includes/update.php(1022): wp_update_plugins() #5 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): _maybe_update_plugins() #6 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #7 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #8 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(175): do_action() #9 /home/sageorvb/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php(10): require_once('/home/sageorvb/...') #10 {main} thrown

I've tried re-installing the plugin but didn't fix it. Error goes away when I deactivate the plugin and reappears when I reactivate.

What might be the cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: First make a database backup… Try to upload Storefront theme and disable all plugins. Switch to storefront theme. Start to enable WooCommerce plugin, and browse your web site to see if there is any issue or error. Then enable the plugins one by one repeating the process. If a plugin is responsible, you will find it. If there is no problem with any plugin, that mean that the responsible is your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after reinstalling the WooCommerce Plugin again.